# Trying to understand a particular part of code from microsoft tutorials regarding Word Add-Ins

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

```
private void ThisAddIn_Startup(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    this.Application.DocumentOpen +=
           new Word.ApplicationEvents4_DocumentOpenEventHandler(WorkWithDocument);

    ((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)this.Application).NewDocument +=
            new > Word.ApplicationEvents4_NewDocumentEventHandler(WorkWithDocument);  
}

private void WorkWithDocument(Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document Doc)
{
    try
    {
            Word.Range rng = Doc.Range(0, 0);
            rng.Text = "New Text";
            rng.Select();
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
            // Handle exception if for some reason the document is not available.
    }
}
```

This is the full code. From what I understand it's supposed to initiate the Add-In, check if the document is avaliable. The part I have trouble understanding is this:

```
((Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)this.Application).NewDocument ...
```

What I don't understand is the `(Word.ApplicationEvents4_Event)` right before `this.Application`. Is that some kind of an event-like typecast? I've got no idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[The documentation states](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event(v=office.14).aspx) that it is an interface, so the code is casting `this.Application` to that interface.

Documentation for [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.application.aspx) explains this:

> This is a .NET interface derived from a COM coclass that is required
>   by managed code for interoperability with the corresponding COM
>   object. Use this derived interface to access all method, property, and
>   event members of the COM object. **However, if a method or event you**
>   **want to use shares the same name under the same COM object, cast to**
>   **the corresponding primary interface to call the method, and cast to**
>   **the latest events interface to connect to the event.** Refer to this
>   topic for information about the COM object. For information about the
>   method and property members of the COM object, see _Application. For
>   information about the event members of the COM object, see
>   ApplicationEvents4_Event.

Answer (score 1):

Addition to Owen's answer:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word.applicationevents4_event.newdocument(v=office.14).aspx

**ApplicationEvents4_Event.NewDocument Event**

Occurs when a new document is created.

So your **WorkWithDocument** method will be called when a document is opened (from your first event subscription) and also when a new document is created (from your second event subscription).

The **+=** just subscribes to those events and tells them to call your method.